# What is the easiest CSS solution (Sass, Tailwind, styled-components, CSS) to use to support two languages on a website?

Tags: css, sass, frontend, tailwind-css, styled-components

I am in the brainstorming phase of a website and trying to select how to write my CSS. The website will support two languages. One language is latin based, think French, and the other is not, think Arabic. Arabic is rtl language. Also, that means menus text are going to change along with other elements. For example if I have a menu button with "Who are we", it must be translated to the other language.

Do I need to define two separate CSS files and pick one based on region/or user selection? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Also, when it comes to changing menu text, do I change only these fields or the entire HTML? Or it depends on the amount of text needs to be changed per HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it, in vanilla JS, is I make a copy of each text element for each language and add language class to it(so I can query select it later). Make a html selector for languages. From JS I add class "hide" to all elements belonging to unselected languages. All CSS that class hide contains is `display:none`. Frameworks, like Angular, contain more elaborate solutions, but for JS this one makes due.

---

**For react** you can use `npm install i18next react-i18next --save`. This solution will leave you with much cleaner view template since there you are just going to name every text field and then in code add to each field its possible translations. As margins, alignments and rest of css goes, usually you don´t even have to touch it, translated text is usually quite similar so if there are breaking differences go with individual solutions. For example, since Arabic is written from right to left, add class with `text-align: right;` when detecting Arabic.

Comment: I am using React.js and was wondering if there is a more elegant solution especially that there will be a lot of changes (margins, alignments.. etc.)

Comment: For future references, a specific tag as "react" is more important than general like "frontend"